# Kafka Connect JDBC dblink

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, dblink

I'm starting to study Apache Kafka and Kafka Connect.
I'm trying to get data from a remote Oracle Database that my user only have read privilegies and can't list tables (i don't have permission to change that). To every query, i have to pass a dblink, but in the JDBC Connector, i didn't find a option to pass a dblink.

I can do the query if i pass a specific query on the connector configuration, but i want to fetch allot of tables and speficifying the query on the connector, would make me create allot of connectors.

There's a way to pass the dblink on the connector configuration or to the JDBC URL?

Comment: Have you tried using Debezium  / GoldenGate instead of JDBC?

Comment: I've tried use Debezium but its the same problem, i couldn't find a way to pass the dblink without passing a specific query